# Change image on uicollectionViewCell from function

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code:

**MainCell.swift :**

```
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView! 
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel! 
    @IBOutlet weak var cellView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellViewOption: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellViewOptionFavorite: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var favoriteBtn1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var favoriteBtn2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var favoriteBtn3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var favoriteIcon1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var favoriteIcon2: UIImageView! 
    @IBOutlet weak var favoriteIcon3: UIImageView!
```

**MainController.swift :**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return productsObjectArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell10", for: indexPath) as! MainViewCollectionViewCell
        cell.titleLabel.text = productsObjectArray[indexPath.item].name
        let documentsDir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let imageFileName = productsObjectArray[indexPath.item].code
        let fullImagePath = documentsDir.appendingPathComponent("GET_PHOTO").path + "/" + imageFileName! + ".jpg"
        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile:   fullImagePath)

        let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MainViewControler.rightSwiped))
        swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
        cell.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

        let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MainViewControler.leftSwiped))
        swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left
        cell.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

        cell.favoriteBtn1.tag =  indexPath.item
        cell.favoriteBtn1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(favoriteBtnPressed1(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        cell.favoriteBtn2.tag =  indexPath.item
        cell.favoriteBtn2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(favoriteBtnPressed2(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        cell.favoriteBtn3.tag =  indexPath.item
        cell.favoriteBtn3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(favoriteBtnPressed3(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }

    @objc func favoriteBtnPressed1(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let productStatus = checkProductFavoriteIsAvailable(favoriteKey: "favoriteProducts1", productId: productsObjectArray[sender.tag].code!)
        if productStatus == true {
            removeProductFromFavorites(favoriteKey: "favoriteProducts1", productId: productsObjectArray[sender.tag].code!)
            changeFavoritesImage(favoriteId: 1, status: 0)
        } else {
            saveProductToFavorites(favoriteKey: "favoriteProducts1", productId: productsObjectArray[sender.tag].code!)
            changeFavoritesImage(favoriteId: 1, status: 1)
        }
    }

    @objc func favoriteBtnPressed2(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let productStatus = checkProductFavoriteIsAvailable(favoriteKey: "favoriteProducts2", productId: productsObjectArray[sender.tag].code!)
        if productStatus == true {
            removeProductFromFavorites(favoriteKey: "favoriteProducts2", productId: productsObjectArray[sender.tag].code!)
            changeFavoritesImage(favoriteId: 2, status: 0)
        } else {
            saveProductToFavorites(favoriteKey: "favoriteProducts2", productId: productsObjectArray[sender.tag].code!)
            changeFavoritesImage(favoriteId: 2, status: 1)
        }
    }

    @objc func favoriteBtnPressed3(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let productStatus = checkProductFavoriteIsAvailable(favoriteKey: "favoriteProducts3", productId: productsObjectArray[sender.tag].code!)
        if productStatus == true {
            removeProductFromFavorites(favoriteKey: "favoriteProducts3", productId: productsObjectArray[sender.tag].code!)
            changeFavoritesImage(favoriteId: 3, status: 0)
        } else {
            saveProductToFavorites(favoriteKey: "favoriteProducts3", productId: productsObjectArray[sender.tag].code!)
            changeFavoritesImage(favoriteId: 3, status: 1)
        }
    }

    func checkProductFavoriteIsAvailable(favoriteKey: String, productId: String) -> Bool{
        var status = false
        if let arr = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: favoriteKey) as? [String]{
            print(arr)
            for favoriteProduct in arr{
                if productId == favoriteProduct {
                    status = true
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        return status
    }

    func saveProductToFavorites(favoriteKey: String, productId: String) {
        if var favoriteArray = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: favoriteKey) {
            if !favoriteArray.contains(productId) {
                favoriteArray.append(productId)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(favoriteArray, forKey: favoriteKey)
            }
        } else {
            let favoriteArray = [productId]
            UserDefaults.standard.set(favoriteArray, forKey: favoriteKey)
        }
    }

    func removeProductFromFavorites(favoriteKey: String, productId: String) {
        guard var favoriteArray = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: favoriteKey),
            let index = favoriteArray.index(of: productId) else { return }
        favoriteArray.remove(at: index)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(favoriteArray, forKey: favoriteKey)
    }

    func changeFavoritesImage(favoriteId: Int, status: Int){
        if favoriteId == 1 && status == 0 {
            favoriteIcon1.image = UIImage(named: "favourites_off_icon.png")
        }
        if favoriteId == 1 && status == 1 {
            favoriteIcon1.image = UIImage(named: "favourites_icon.png")
        }

        if favoriteId == 2 && status == 0 {
            favoriteIcon2.image = UIImage(named: "favourites_off_icon.png")
        }
        if favoriteId == 2 && status == 1 {
            favoriteIcon2.image = UIImage(named: "favourites_icon.png")
        }

        if favoriteId == 3 && status == 0{
            favoriteIcon3.image = UIImage(named: "favourites_off_icon.png")
        }
        if favoriteId == 3 && status == 1 {
            favoriteIcon3.image = UIImage(named: "favourites_icon.png")
        }
    }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let productObject = productsObjectArray[indexPath.item]
        showSubViewInContainerViewProductCard(view: "ProductDetailView", object: [productObject], productsFilter: 0, marketProductsFilter: 0, menuFilter: 0, preparationFilter: 0, glutenFilter: 0,  backFromProductView: false)
    }
```

In the `changeFavoritesImage` function, I would like to change the images to `UICollectionViewCell`.
Error :

```
Mam błąd: Use of unresolved identifier 'favoriteIcon3', Use of unresolved identifier 'favoriteIcon2', Use of unresolved identifier 'favoriteIcon1'
```

My code displays a list of products. I have on it buttons that add these products to favorites, watched, etc.
I would like to change the picture in the product list depending on the status of the product.

How to fix it?

Comment: `favoriteIcon1, favoriteIcon2, favoriteIcon3` are members of `MainViewCollectionViewCell` not `MainController` so you should access them by accessing cell first at that index.

Comment: exactly, and how to do it?

Comment: I think the answer below gives the right pointer on how to achieve this. Unrelated but I have one recommendation, You should move all gestures logic inside cell class i.e, `MainViewCollectionViewCell`, create a model property in cell and assign the model from `cellForRowAt`. This way you will avoid many repetitions and if else conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your method as following

```
func changeFavoritesImage(ofSender sender:UIButton,favoriteId: Int, status: Int){

    guard let cell = collectionview.cellForItem(at: IndexPath.init(item: sender.tag, section: 0)) as? MainViewCollectionViewCell else {return} 

    if favoriteId == 1 && status == 0 {
        cell.favoriteIcon1.image = UIImage(named: "favourites_off_icon.png")
    }
    if favoriteId == 1 && status == 1 {
        cell.favoriteIcon1.image = UIImage(named: "favourites_icon.png")
    }

    if favoriteId == 2 && status == 0 {
        favoriteIcon2.image = UIImage(named: "favourites_off_icon.png")
    }
    if favoriteId == 2 && status == 1 {
        cell.favoriteIcon2.image = UIImage(named: "favourites_icon.png")
    }

    if favoriteId == 3 && status == 0{
        cell.favoriteIcon3.image = UIImage(named: "favourites_off_icon.png")
    }
    if favoriteId == 3 && status == 1 {
        cell.favoriteIcon3.image = UIImage(named: "favourites_icon.png")
    }
}
```

and change your method call in your button actions as below

```
@objc func favoriteBtnPressed1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let productStatus = checkProductFavoriteIsAvailable(favoriteKey: "favoriteProducts1", productId: productsObjectArray[sender.tag].code!)
    if productStatus == true {
        removeProductFromFavorites(favoriteKey: "favoriteProducts1", productId: productsObjectArray[sender.tag].code!)
        changeFavoritesImage(ofSender:sender,favoriteId: 1, status: 0)
    } else {
        saveProductToFavorites(favoriteKey: "favoriteProducts1", productId: productsObjectArray[sender.tag].code!)
        changeFavoritesImage(ofSender:sender,favoriteId: 1, status: 1)
    }
}

@objc func favoriteBtnPressed2(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let productStatus = checkProductFavoriteIsAvailable(favoriteKey: "favoriteProducts2", productId: productsObjectArray[sender.tag].code!)
    if productStatus == true {
        removeProductFromFavorites(favoriteKey: "favoriteProducts2", productId: productsObjectArray[sender.tag].code!)
         changeFavoritesImage(ofSender:sender,favoriteId: 2, status: 0)
    } else {
        saveProductToFavorites(favoriteKey: "favoriteProducts2", productId: productsObjectArray[sender.tag].code!)
        changeFavoritesImage(ofSender:sender,favoriteId: 2, status: 1)
    }
}

@objc func favoriteBtnPressed3(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let productStatus = checkProductFavoriteIsAvailable(favoriteKey: "favoriteProducts3", productId: productsObjectArray[sender.tag].code!)
    if productStatus == true {
        removeProductFromFavorites(favoriteKey: "favoriteProducts3", productId: productsObjectArray[sender.tag].code!)
        changeFavoritesImage(ofSender:sender,favoriteId: 3, status: 0)
    } else {
        saveProductToFavorites(favoriteKey: "favoriteProducts3", productId: productsObjectArray[sender.tag].code!)
        changeFavoritesImage(ofSender:sender,favoriteId: 3, status: 1)
    }
}
```

in above code i have just change the implementation of your method to accept sender argument so we can use that to get cell as shown in code

Comment: Answers are more helpful with an explanation of the problem and the solution, instead of a "try this" code dump only.

Comment: I have error: Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' has no member 'favoriteIcon1', Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' has no member 'favoriteIcon2', Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' has no member 'favoriteIcon3'